# dynamic f.collection_select how can i call javascript function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This is my code and in this i wanna call a java script function on some condition like if a = 1 than call hi() function and a = 2 than call hello() function

```
<%= f.collection_select :ser_id, @ser, :id, :name, :prompt => true -%>
```

Javascript function are

```
function hi()
{
alert("hi");
}

function hello()
{
alert("hello");
}
```

So now give me some idea that how can i call these to function according to given condition.

Comment: Take a look on edited answers .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
<% fun_name = "" %>
<% fun_name = (a==1 ? "eval('hi()')" : "eval('hello()')") if a==1 || a==2 %>
<%= f.collection_select :ser_id, @ser, :id, :name, :prompt => true, {:onchange => fun_name } -%>
```